# Bootstrap Columns with height defined as percentage of row width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

## Complex Grid Layout, Help!

I'm making a responsive website using bootstrap 3.0.2 and can't figure out the layout that is stated in the requirements document for the project. I made an image of what I need, and will give more detail, or update my question, if needed. I am open to any suggestion on how to accomplish this.

### The Issue

This image describes what I need the design to look like at three different widths.

**I should add**, each box will be basically a div with an image, article title and summary within it.

[image]

### Like to say ... in advanced

Id like to say thanks and apologize in advanced if the question is dumb or the answer is obvious. I have been a dev for a long time, but I'm new to responsive design and I've been banging my head on the wall trying to get this to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic part of your project is to make two smaller blocks side with a bigger one and make these two 50%. As far as I know, there are no mature cross-browser solutions that would accomplish that without javascript.

You may want to take a look at: [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and for Comrade IE [Flexie](http://flexiejs.com/).

Another approach to accomplish the same could be using [viewport dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1575141/2066118). Just be aware of the [browsers support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

All in all, if you can do that, I would suggest just using JS, with a fallback to css that will not break the site's look too much. Having just finished a project with similar requirements, I would just like to say good luck.

Comment: Im selecting this as the answer because it is a viable option, but also the only answer I got ;-)

Comment: HOWEVER, if I remember correctly I ended up getting lucky and with the just the right image dimensions I lucked out and it scaled perfectly ;-)